# Abstract classes and interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

In an Interface by default the data member are static and final.
Static it is because it can not be instantiated,but why it is final?

and the other question is even the abstract classes can not be instantiated,then why it can have a non static data member??

Comment: before enums interfaces contains a lot of constants

Comment: I think it iss a good question and the probable answer is something like because the JLS says so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
and the other question is even the abstract classes can not be instantiated,
then why it can have a non static data member??
```

Because in abstract classes, you can define as much functionality you want, which can be then used by its childs.

Answer (score 0):

Interface variables are static because Java interfaces cannot be instantiated in their own right; the value of the variable must be assigned in a static context in which no instance exists. The final modifier ensures the value assigned to the interface variable is a true constant that cannot be re-assigned by program code.

I wouldn't advise on putting variables in an interface since the interface mainly serves as a blueprint for it's classes.

**Why can an abstract class have a non-static data member?**

A static variable is one that’s associated with a class, not objects of that class. Generally speaking, the purpose of an abstract class is to provide a skeleton with some non-abstract behavior, but other bits still to be filled in by subclasses which can also define functionality and use the abstract class' variables.